# i cannot invoke the function in login.html which is specified after the import statement in login.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-modules, node-mysql2

This is my code

login.html-----------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>RavenL0gin</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
    <script type="module" src="./login.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./connect.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logincont">
        <div>
           <img src="boylog.png">
           <img src="girllog.jpeg">
           <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User-Name" onchange=incre()><br>
           <span id="usernameerr"></span><br>
           <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" onchange=incre()><br>
           <span id="passworderr"></span><br>
           <button onclick=comp() id="but">Login</button>
           <p>Did'nt Register yet?<a href="#">Register Now</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

login.js------------------------------------------------------

```
import  {rows}  from "./connect.js";

console.log(rows)

 let nm=0;
 let pwd=0;

 export default function incre(){
    for(let i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        if(rows[i].uname==document.getElementById("username").value){
            nm++;
            console.log(nm);
        }
        if(rows[i].pwd==document.getElementById("pwd").value){
            pwd++;
        }
 }
}

export default function comp(){
    document.getElementById("but").style.marginLeft="23px";
    document.getElementById("pwd").style.marginLeft="32px";


        if(nm==0){
            document.getElementById("usernameerr").innerText="Invalid Username";
            document.getElementById("but").style.marginTop="20px";


        }
        if(pwd==0){
            document.getElementById("passworderr").innerText="Invalid Password";
            document.getElementById("but").style.marginTop="20px";
        }

        if(nm>0 && pwd>0){
           window.location.replace("main.html");
        }
   
        num=0;
        pwd=0;
    }
```

connect.js-------------------------------------------------------

```
import mysql from "mysql2";



const pool=mysql.createPool({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"root123",
    database:"vishnu"
}).promise();




const result=await pool.query("select * from login");
const rows=result[0];
console.log(rows)

export {rows};
```

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfqYh.jpg)
So this is my code guys as you see I complicated a lot in this mess but still I hope you guys understand and give me a solution. I will be glad if anyone replies me

Answer (score 0):

When defining properties in HTML tags you need to put quotation marks "" or '' around the value:

```js
function comp(){
    console.log("Hello!");
}
```

```html
 <button onclick="comp()" id="but">Login</button>
```

Comment: hey bro thank you for replying but still i get this error like;       [login.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "mysql2". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".]. But when i run login.js on terminal there is no errors and still the onclick is not working.When i comment the import statement it works properly but i need that data for validation

Comment: Hey, no problem. That'll be a completely different question as it's unrelated to the click binding not working. Either that module doesn't exist or you're not importing it properly, so the code is breaking before reaching the code with the click binding.